# Как использовать Ninject для привязки Service Reference

Tags: c#, wcf, dependency-injection

У меня в solution два проекта WCF и MVC. В проекте MVC использую [Ninject.Extensions.Wcf.Client](https://github.com/cyanfish/Ninject.Extensions.Wcf.Client), 
В обоих проектах использую интерфейс `Shop.Services.Abstract.IUserService`

```cs
[ServiceContract(Name = "IUserService")]
public interface IUserService
{
    [OperationContract]
    UserBM Create(UserBM user, string password);

    [OperationContract]
    void Update(UserBM user, string pass = null, bool changePassword = false);

    [OperationContract]
    UserBM GetById(Guid id);

    [OperationContract]
    void Delete(UserBM user);

    [OperationContract]
    UserBM LogOn(string eMail, string pass);

    [OperationContract]
    List<UserBM> GetAllUsers();
}
```

Когда создаю 'service reference' в проекте MVC, сервис создает свое пространство имен Shop.Web.UserSeviceClient.IUserService, получается у меня интерфейсы отличаются только пространством имен,

```cs
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
public partial class UserServiceClient : 
    System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<Shop.Web.UserSeviceClient.IUserService>, 
    Shop.Web.UserSeviceClient.IUserService 
{   
    public UserServiceClient() 
    {
    }

    public UserServiceClient(string endpointConfigurationName) : 
        base(endpointConfigurationName) 
    {
    }

    public UserServiceClient(string endpointConfigurationName, string remoteAddress) : 
        base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress) 
    {
    }
}
```

для того чтобы использовать Ninject нужно чтобы интерфейсы были одинаковы, поэтому не могу привязать UserServiceClient (`Shop.Web.UserSeviceClient.IUserService`) к интерфейсу `Shop.Services.Abstract.IUserService`

```cs
private void AddBindings() 
{
    ninjectKernel.Bind<IUserService>().ToServiceChannel("BasicHttpBinding_IUserService");
}
```

Может кто сталкивался с такой проблемой? помогите если не трудно)

Comment: Почему не можете? Привязывайте сколько душе угодно.

Другое дело, что вы в mvc проекте должны использовать то, что вам студия сгенерила, а не напрямую из wcf-проекта интерфейс использовать.

Answer (score 1):

Совершенно не обязательно добавлять Service Reference, чтобы пользоваться сервисом - есть и другие способы. Более того, `Ninject.Extensions.Wcf.Client` именно эти самые "другие способы" и использует - то есть вам класс `UserServiceClient` вообще не нужен!

Удаляйте Service Reference из проекта, но оставьте биндинги в файле web.config - они пригодятся.